# Using a key to replace values across a whole data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, plyr

I have a large data table which looks as follows:

```
    V1              V2           V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9
1: XS0285400197 TR.IssuerRating  F1  F1  F1  F1  F1  F1  F1
2: XS0041971275 TR.IssuerRating AAA AAA AAA AAA  F1  F1  AAA
3: XS0043098127 TR.IssuerRating  WD  WD  WD  WD  WD  WD  WD

structure(list(V1 = c("XS0285400197", "XS0041971275", "XS0043098127"
), V2 = c("TR.IssuerRating", "TR.IssuerRating", "TR.IssuerRating"
), V3 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"), V4 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"), V5 = c("F1", 
"AAA", "WD"), V6 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"), V7 = c("F1", "F1", "WD"
), V8 = c("F1", "F1", "WD"), V9 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

The actual data table is much larger but this should serve as an example. Additionally, I have a key where I want to replace the ratings (here F1,AAA and WD) with numbers.

```
    Rating CreditQuality
1:   F1               2
2:  AAA               1
3:  WD                6
4:  (P)B2             6
5: (P)Ba1             4
6: (P)Ba2             5

structure(list(Rating = c("F1", "AAA", "WD", "(P)B2", "(P)Ba1", 
"(P)Ba2"), CreditQuality = c(2L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to replace these ratings with the CreditQuality I have assigned each rating in the key. This would mean that a cell with F1 is now a 2. A cell with WD would be a 6 and so on. The new table should look as follows:

```
    V1              V2           V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9
1: XS0285400197 TR.IssuerRating   2   2   2   2  2    2  2
2: XS0041971275 TR.IssuerRating   1   1   1   1  2    2  1
3: XS0043098127 TR.IssuerRating   6   6   6   6  6    6  6
```

I have tried using `match` and `mapvalues` however `match` only seems to work for a single column and `mapvalues` only works for an atomic vector not for a data.table. Some people have had similar problems however most of them only needed to replace values in a single column whereas I want to replace values across multiple columns in a data.table

Comment: Please make your examples reproducible with dput() or similiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `melt` and `dcast`:

```
dcast(
  rating[melt(df, id=c("V1", "V2"),value.name = "Rating"), on="Rating"],
  V1+V2~variable, value.var = "CreditQuality"
)
```

Output:

```
             V1              V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
1: XS0041971275 TR.IssuerRating  1  1  1  1  2  2  1
2: XS0043098127 TR.IssuerRating  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
3: XS0285400197 TR.IssuerRating  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Note: I'm assuming your source data is `df`, and your Rating data is `rating`. I see that your frames are already of class `data.table`

Comment: Yes my data frames are already in the `data.table` format. This worked very well thanks! Does your method automatically sort by V1? Not that this is a problem.

Comment: Good question. The `dcast()` function returns a *keyed* data.table, where the key columns are the variables in the left hand side of the formula. In this case, that left hand side is `V1+V2`, so YES, the result will be ordered by V1 and then V2. -- See documentation for `data.table::dcast()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr` and `across`.

```
library(dplyr)

# Define input data
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("XS0285400197", "XS0041971275", "XS0043098127"),
  V2 = c("TR.IssuerRating", "TR.IssuerRating", "TR.IssuerRating"),
  V3 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"),
  V4 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"),
  V5 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"),
  V6 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"),
  V7 = c("F1", "F1", "WD"),
  V8 = c("F1", "F1", "WD"),
  V9 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

lookup <- data.frame(
  Rating = c("F1", "AAA", "WD", "(P)B2", "(P)Ba1", "(P)Ba2"),
  CreditQuality = c(2, 1, 6, 6, 4, 5)
)

# Make a look up vector
lookup_vec <- lookup$CreditQuality
names(lookup_vec) <- lookup$Rating

# Use dplyr across to apply look up
df_mod <- df %>%
  mutate(across(seq(3, dim(df)[2]), ~ lookup_vec[.x]))

# View
df_mod

#             V1              V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
# 1 XS0285400197 TR.IssuerRating  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
# 2 XS0041971275 TR.IssuerRating  1  1  1  1  2  2  1
# 3 XS0043098127 TR.IssuerRating  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      V1 = c("XS0285400197", "XS0041971275", "XS0043098127"),
      V2 = c("TR.IssuerRating", "TR.IssuerRating", "TR.IssuerRating"),
      V3 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"),
      V4 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"),
      V5 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"),
      V6 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"),
      V7 = c("F1", "F1", "WD"),
      V8 = c("F1", "F1", "WD"),
      V9 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD")),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-3L)
  )

rating <-
  structure(list(
    Rating = c("F1", "AAA", "WD", "(P)B2", "(P)Ba1", "(P)Ba2"),
    CreditQuality = c(2L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L)),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-6L))

df
#>             V1              V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 V7 V8  V9
#> 1 XS0285400197 TR.IssuerRating  F1  F1  F1  F1 F1 F1  F1
#> 2 XS0041971275 TR.IssuerRating AAA AAA AAA AAA F1 F1 AAA
#> 3 XS0043098127 TR.IssuerRating  WD  WD  WD  WD WD WD  WD

#tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(V3:V9, ~with(rating, CreditQuality[match(.x, table = Rating)])))
#>             V1              V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
#> 1 XS0285400197 TR.IssuerRating  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
#> 2 XS0041971275 TR.IssuerRating  1  1  1  1  2  2  1
#> 3 XS0043098127 TR.IssuerRating  6  6  6  6  6  6  6

# base
df[, 3:9] <- sapply(df[ ,3:9], function(x) with(rating, CreditQuality[match(x, table = Rating)]))
df
#>             V1              V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
#> 1 XS0285400197 TR.IssuerRating  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
#> 2 XS0041971275 TR.IssuerRating  1  1  1  1  2  2  1
#> 3 XS0043098127 TR.IssuerRating  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**In base R:**

```
lut     = with(B, setNames(CreditQuality, Rating))
vars    = paste0("V", 3:9)
A[vars] = lapply(A[vars], \(x) lut[x])

#             V1              V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
# 1 XS0285400197 TR.IssuerRating  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
# 2 XS0041971275 TR.IssuerRating  1  1  1  1  2  2  1
# 3 XS0043098127 TR.IssuerRating  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
```

**Same logic in `data.table`:**

```
setDT(A)
A[, (vars) := lapply(.SD, \(x) lut[x]), .SDcols = vars]
```

**Data**

```
A = structure(list(V1 = c("XS0285400197", "XS0041971275", "XS0043098127"
), V2 = c("TR.IssuerRating", "TR.IssuerRating", "TR.IssuerRating"
), V3 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"), V4 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"), V5 = c("F1", 
"AAA", "WD"), V6 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD"), V7 = c("F1", "F1", "WD"
), V8 = c("F1", "F1", "WD"), V9 = c("F1", "AAA", "WD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

B = structure(list(Rating = c("F1", "AAA", "WD", "(P)B2", "(P)Ba1", 
"(P)Ba2"), CreditQuality = c(2L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```